# closeOnSelect=false breaks arrow key focus on dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

When I set multiple="multiple" and closeOnSelect: false, I can no longer focus on items in the dropdown list by pressing the down arrow (while focused on the search box). I can select multiple items using mouse (this part works perfectly). It's just getting the focus from the search box to the dropdown list and keeping the focus there even after selection of multiple items.

Here what I've been using...

```
$(function(){
    $('#option').select2({
      closeOnSelect: false
    });
});

<select id="option" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px;">
    <option value="afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="american_samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="andorra">Andorra</option>
</select>
```

And here's an attempted fix that doesn't actually work (but maybe I'm on the right track??)...

```
$('.select2-input').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        $('.select2-results-dept-0')
        .removeClass('select2-highlighted')
        .eq(0)
        .addClass('select2-highlighted');
    }
});
```